# Does AWS have a dummy API for testing?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Does Amazon Web Services provide a dummy API for testing?

I want to test my paginated API call logic for that I do not have that much resources. Does AWS provide any kind of dummy data to test my API call logic?

I have tried to find but all I can find is people creating resources and then checking the API.

```
final AmazonEC2 ec2 = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
boolean done = false;

while(!done) {
    DescribeInstancesRequest request = new DescribeInstancesRequest();
    DescribeInstancesResult response = ec2.describeInstances(request);

    for(Reservation reservation : response.getReservations()) {
        for(Instance instance : reservation.getInstances()) {
            System.out.printf(
                "Found reservation with id %s, " +
                "AMI %s, " +
                "type %s, " +
                "state %s " +
                "and monitoring state %s",
                instance.getInstanceId(),
                instance.getImageId(),
                instance.getInstanceType(),
                instance.getState().getName(),
                instance.getMonitoring().getState());
        }
    }

    request.setNextToken(response.getNextToken());

    if(response.getNextToken() == null) {
        done = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no dummy API available. Everything is "production".

The AWS Python SDK (boto3) has a `dry-run` feature for some calls that will simply return *whether* the call would have succeeded, but it does not return dummy data.